# Excel: How to merge two columns into one (from different sheets or separated columns)

Tags: excel

I have met some problem with merging two columns to one.
I have some solution but not exactly fits to my problem (found here: [Excel: Merge two columns into one column with alternating values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637400/excel-merge-two-columns-into-one-column-with-alternating-values))

As I understand two columns has to be one by one:

```
A       B       C
==================
A       1       A
B       2       1
C       3       B
                2
                C
                3
```

To get the above solution in C column I should use:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$9;ROUND(ROW(A1)/2;0);MOD(ROW();2)+1)
```

So in the formula I'm using data like `A1:B4`.

How to do it if I will have columns with data A and D and I dont want to include columns B and C?
Or for instance I will have one column from sheet_A and second column from sheet_B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula is total flexible. You can have your two seperate columns on different sheets. And the Result column also can be wherever you want.

```
=IF(ISEVEN(ROW())=FALSE;INDEX($A$4:$A$20;ROUND((ROWS($A$4:A4)/2);0));INDEX($B$6:$B$24;ROUND((ROWS($B$6:B6)/2);0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely the best possible answer!

Answer (score 3):

The Index function can be used in two different way. This example use the index function with multiple range area. The 4th parameter is the sequence number of the individual reference range.

Here is the equation for the result combined in one column.

```
=LET(RC,ROW(M9)-ROW($M$8),Rx,IF(ISODD(RC),(RC+1)/2,RC/2),Ax,IF(ISODD(RC),1,2),INDEX(($F$11:$F$20,$I$18:$I$27),Rx,,Ax))
```

RC is the variable representing the row in the result column.  Rx represent the row in the reference area, Ax is the reference area number.

NOTE: M9 is my 1st row in the RC column

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it correctly, so in your example the source_1 is F11:F20 and source_2 is I18:I27?
So what did you set as RC Ax and Rx?
I have also prepared the example sheet, if you prefer to add here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w2BODk57DIGfB8b5eStjcKqsYanCnxc-jEL68DENpZw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula is in M9 to M28.  RC is the index 1 to 20 for the RC column. Rx is the row index for A1 column and A2 column.  Cx is the index to select either the  A1 or A2 range.

Comment: This uses the Reference form of the Index function as describe in this link.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd

Comment: @tomm I added the formula to the google sheet, but it does not support this form for the Index function. I get a parse error and I cannot drag it down.  You did indicates reference to excel for this question.

Comment: Correction in my comment above,  Ax is the index to select either the A1 or A2 range.

Comment: Yeah, true but it's still helping a lot ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to your formula, then you could modify it like this:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AncAhUkdErOkguUaToQkVkl5Qw-l_g?e=5d9gVM

Odd Start row

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$9;ROUND(ROW(A1)/2;0);IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$2);2)=1;4;1))
```

Even Start row

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$9;ROUND(ROW(A1)/2;0);IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$1);2)=1;4;1))
```

What is A1 in the picture is the cell directly above your first data cell.

[image]

If you want to place it on a different sheet you just add the sheet name:

```
=INDEX(MySheet!$A$2:$D$9;ROUND(ROW(MySheet!A1)/2;0);IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW(MySheet!$A$2);2)=1;4;1))
=INDEX(MySheet!$A$2:$D$9;ROUND(ROW(MySheet!A1)/2;0);IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW(MySheet!$A$1);2)=1;4;1))
```

Comment: That works for me perfectly, even in my test sheet in google docs. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I have one more example. What if one of the column is in sheet1 and second in sheet2?

Comment: @tomm that might get even more complicated. I might not be able to figure it out. But you could make a new sheet, where you combine the columns from different sheets into one sheet. On that new sheet, you can use the formula above.

Comment: Yeah, I know, just thinking about solution kinda "all in one". Anyway thank you, I will try to do something like this :)

Comment: @tomm When I woke up today I had an idea how to fix this. Very simple formula. See my new answer.

Comment: Yeah, you are my google sheets master :)