# Excel : How to merge two dynamic arrays into one dynamic array, with alternating rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays, array-merge

I have two dynamic arrays, A1# and B1#. I want to combine them into a dynamic array, C1#, like so:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 4 | x |
| y | 5 | 4 |
| z | 6 | y |
|  |  | 5 ... |

Currently, I am using the solution provided via WeAreOne's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022776/excel-how-to-merge-two-columns-into-one-from-different-sheets-or-separated-col), of which I have also seen a few different similar answers:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(ROW())=FALSE,INDEX($A$1:$A$3,ROUND((ROWS($A$1:A1)/2),0)),INDEX($B$1:$B$3,ROUND((ROWS($B$1:B1)/2),0)))
```

(entered into C1 and dragged down).

However, the arrays I am merging are often changing length drastically, and so I am looking for the neater solution of returning a dynamic array, rather than dragging down my current formula in anticipation of the merged array's length and also having to alter the references to the initial arrays.

Comment: So you don't have `VSTACK`, then?

Comment: @JosWoolley I need the final array to have alternating rows, but I'd happily use VSTACK if you could suggest how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `TOCOL()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=DROP(TOCOL(A:B,3),2)
```

---

As **[Ike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16578424/ike)** Ma'am mentioned in comments, you can use it this way as well,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=TOCOL(A2#:B2#,3)
```

---

Comment: As OP said A and B are dynamic arrays `TOCOL(A#:B#)` should work as well

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks to the both of you - a lot easier than what I previously had!